# Java: Call method by Timer, but changes made by called method dont remain outside TimerTask

Tags: java, timer, guava, timertask, multimap

I want that a particular method is called after a certain delay. I tried different aproaches likes timer, executor or handlers. They fullfill what they are supposed to do, but with a little exception. The delayed method call makes some changes in a multimap from guava. Within the `run`-method of the TimerTask the output is like I want it. But if I print the multimap outside of `run` the changes are withdrawn and I still have the old multimap values. But I need the updated ones, because my data is saved in it and I need the updated values to work with.

My code looks like that:

```
public class classTimer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //some code, irrelevant for the task

             new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {          
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 dataMap = UndoManager.undoChanges(dataMap, a, hw); 
                 // Point 1  
                    }
                }, delay);  
                // Point 2
   }
 }
```

Like I said before, printing the `dataMap` at Point1 gives the correct output, at Point 2 the old values, like the Method `UndoChanges` was newer called. Multimaps are implemented that changes stay consistent and normally the values must have been changed, but thats not the case here. What am I missing here? If somebody knows a different method to call a method after a delay, I would be happy to hear it.

Thanks and much appreciated

Comment: Point 2 happens before point one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Point 2 in your code executes immediately after you *schedule* the undo task. This is because the `schedule` method returns immediately: it doesn't wait for the delay to pass and the task to be executed. That is really the point of using Timers: schedule *asynchronous* tasks to run at some time in the future.

Comment: Didnt thought about that, because the delay is in the microseconds area, but you are right, thanks for that.